# Why is getopt's optarg variable zero during debugging?

Tags: c, gdb

I noticed during debugging that the `optarg` variable of GNU's [getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html) remained `zero` (i.e. address 0x0) during debugging. But when `optarg` is used as right-hand operand of assignment or passed as argument to a parameter, the expected value is applied. The example from GNU:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int aflag = 0;
  int bflag = 0;
  char *cvalue = NULL;
  int index;
  int c;

  opterr = 0;

  while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "abc:")) != -1)
    switch (c)
      {
      case 'a':
        aflag = 1;
        break;
      case 'b':
        bflag = 1;
        break;
      case 'c':          # b 26
        cvalue = optarg; # gdb stops right before executing this line
        break;
      case '?':
        if (optopt == 'c')
          fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
        else if (isprint (optopt))
          fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
        else
          fprintf (stderr,
                   "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                   optopt);
        return 1;
      default:
        abort ();
      }

  printf ("aflag = %d, bflag = %d, cvalue = %s\n",
          aflag, bflag, cvalue);

  for (index = optind; index < argc; index++)
    printf ("Non-option argument %s\n", argv[index]);
  return 0;
}
```

**Usage**

```
$ gcc -o getopt getopt.c -g # debugging ON, optimizations OFF
$ gdb getopt
(gdb) b 26 # set breakpoint
(gdb) r -cfoo
(gdb) p optarg
$1 = 0x0 # no "foo"?
(gdb) n # executes cvalue = optarg
(gdb) p cvalue
$2 = 0x7fffffffea99 "foo" # here it is, please don't expect to get the same memory-address
```

Why `optarg` doesn't contain the character string "foo" at line 26? What do I miss here?

More bewildering, I figured out it doesn't contain "foo" even after the line has been executed. I've put a glance at the [original source](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libiberty/getopt.c;h=5d9bcaadd90f2245a753bb5b8e362fcd0a6432bf;hb=HEAD) and didn't notice something like a compiler optimization. I'm using GCC 11.1.0 on Archlinux, x86_64.

Thank you

Comment: Where, *exactly*, is your breakpoint were you examine the value of `optarg`? Please add a comment on that line in the shown code.

Comment: Please indicate which line is 26

Comment: Also think about that while all [manual pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) show the `optarg` declaration as `extern char *optarg;` it may actually be implemented as a macro (just like `errno` typically is).

Comment: The debugger halts directly before executing "cvalue = optarg". At that point optarg is zero, I go ahead with 'n' and after the assignment cvalue has the the value "foo" but optarg is still zero.

Comment: @Peter -- Does your program still work?  If so, then this is a debugger issue, not an issue with the program itself.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes. Perfectly!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In the original source it is defined as 'char *optarg = NULL;' you can use the link the question above, line 115.

Comment: I figured out (with tabbing) that I can see the actual value with p (char*)'optarg@GLIBC_2.2.5'
$6 = 0x7fffffffea99 "foo". I found two posts about the ABI changes, but regarding C++ only:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575687/why-can-gdb-not-see-a-global-variable
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820535/can-not-print-global-objects-in-gdb

Answer (score 0):

PaulMcKenzie seems right. It is probably this old [bug 8588](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8588) within GDB. GDB struggles handling the [GOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Offset_Table) (Global-Offset-Table) right which is a part of [PIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) (Position-Independent-Code].

**Workaround**

```
p (char*)'optarg@GLIBC_2.2.5'
```

We reference here the variable `optarg` and the [version symbol](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458664/125080) of the GLIBC. The version `2.2.5` is the baseline which already includes provides GNU getopt and therefore the newer ones don't apply.

Thank you